# JupyterLab: increase input code cell maximum height and disable vertical scrolling

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

**How do I increase the maximum default cell height or disable individual vertical scrolling for code (input) cells?**

By default, input code cells in JupyterLab have a limited height. Once the maximum height is exceeded, the scrollbar is added. This resulted in two scrollbars - one for the whole notebook and another one for long cells, resulting in poor user experience.

For the record, long cells are rendered as is in the classical Jupyter Notebooks and therefore are easier to navigate.

P.S. Making cells smaller is not a viable option when you work with embedded SQL text and in general is not preferred. I also like to merge cells (with utility functions) together, to minimize out-of-order execution, that is a curse of interactive programming.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following line into the *CodeMirror* settings:

```
"scrollbarStyle":null
```

under the menu `Settings->Raw View->CodeMirror->User Overrides`. Its documentation can be found [here](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_scrollbarStyle).

I cannot test it because in my JupyterLab the scrollbar never shows up, no matter how many lines (up to 300) of codes that I put in the notebook cell. I am using JupyterLab 0.35.3 and firefox 65.0 (also tested on Chrome 72.0).

Comment: Does not seem to make any difference for me. This is what I add there `{"scrollbarStyle":null}`. I have 180 lines and the scroll bar is there :(

Comment: Which version of JupyterLab and browser are you using?

Comment: JupyterLab: Version 0.35.4, Chrome: 72, MacOS: 10.13

Answer (score 0):

Having the same feeling and not knowing what am I doing, just experimenting with it .. I looked up the element in dev-tools having the scrollbar ..
and modified this file :
.jupyter\custom\custom.css
containing the last entry:

```
/* Make the notebook cells take almost all available width */
.container {
    width: 98% !important;
}

/* Prevent the edit cell highlight box from getting clipped;
 * important so that it also works when cell is in edit mode*/

div.cell.selected {
    border-left-width: 1px !important;
}
div.output_scroll {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```